# How do I send an array of json files from the server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

I'm using vue.js. I've written the following code but it's not working, how can I fix it?

Here is my code:

```js
 mounted(){
    fetch('/', {
    method: 'POST', // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
    mode: 'cors', // no-cors, *cors, same-origin    
    headers: {
       'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
    },
   
  })
    .then(response => response.json())    
    .then(json => this.firstWindow = json)
    
    // .then(json => console.log(json))
    // .then(console.log(this.firstWindow))
    
  },
```

Server part here

```js
router.post('/',(req, res) =>{  // request for sending file
    console.log("POST");
    // res.sendFile(myModule.dataOfScreens);
    res.sendFile(path.resolve('./data/firstScreen.json'));
})
```

Comment: " It is absolutely wrong" - **how** is it wrong?

Comment: it doesn't work ......

Comment: I don't know how to send and process this array right

Comment: Do you want to send an array of JSON to the server from the client(vuejs)?

Comment: from server to client

Comment: Then API should be GET request.

Comment: You can try maybe load the json file and send it back as json response?

Answer (score 0):

Your are trying to **get** a file from the server, but you are using the *POST* method !!!

If this is what your are trying to do, so you should do something like this:

```
router.get('/filesFolder?:fileName', function(req, res){
    let filePath = '.. the path of your local files folder ..+ '/' +req.query.fileName
    if (fs.existsSync(filePath)) {
      //file exists
      res.sendFile(filePath);
    }
  });
```

Where filesFolder is the folder's name in which you store your files; fileName is the name of the file you are requesting; filePath is the path under filesFolder of the requested file.